# Move activity to front in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

In an activity, I have created a AsyncTask after hiding the activity:

```
this.moveTaskToBack(true);
(new MyTask(this)).execute();
```

To show a dialog in the task (in `onPostExcecute`), I want to bring the activity to front:

```
alertDialog.show();

Intent intent = new Intent(mainActivity, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
mainActivity.getBaseContext().startActivity(intent);
```

But a new instance of the main activity is created and shown on top of the dialog, although the application was still running (the activity has also a dialog style Theme.Dialog). How should I fix this?

Edit: According to [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent,%20android.os.Bundle%29), this code always recreates the activity and doesn't bring its previous instance to front, since startActivity is called from outside of an Activity Context.

Comment: Maybe move `alertDialog.show()` to after the `startActivity()` call.

Comment: @MikeM. That didn't work either.

Comment: Try using FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT as additional flags

Comment: @SachinGadagi Thanks for reply. I tried it, but the dialog is still behind the activity.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a new piece of information to that intent, and catching it in `onCreate()`?

What I mean is something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String WANT_DIALOG_EXTRA = "WANT_DIALOG_EXTRA";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getIntent().hasExtra(WANT_DIALOG_EXTRA)) {
            // create and show dialog
        }
    }

}
```

Then when you create your intent, add one more line like this:

```
intent.putExtra(MainActivity.WANT_DIALOG_EXTRA, true);
```

Comment: Thanks. If I create the dialog in the main activity, then how should I invoke a method of the AsyncTask after user clicks on a button of the dialog? My task has still some work to do.

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing what your code does, but maybe there's a different way you could structure it. Maybe the dialog could start a second AsyncTask.